# How to change background color of tr td within a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the background color of td elements in my table, but the browser keeps saying **"Cannot read property 'children' of undefined"**
JS is able to navigate thru all the records, but the color never changes due to the error.

This is my table

```
<div id="GruposCxPPago">
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text2</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

This is my Javascript

```
var ele = new Array();
$("#GruposCxPPago").find('tr').each(function(i)
   {
      var item = ele[i];  
      item.children('td').each(function(tdEL) {
          tdEl.css({"background-color":"red"});
      });
});
```

Comment: This means item is undefined...Did you check for ele[i] != undefined?

Answer (score 1):

Use simply this: `$("#GruposCxPPago td").css({"background-color":"red"});`

```js
$("#GruposCxPPago td").css({"background-color":"red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="GruposCxPPago">
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text2</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```js
$("#GruposCxPPago td").each(function()
   $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
});
```